# Filter out rows retrospectively in SSRS

Tags: filter, reporting-services, rows

I have a table that has three columns: Worker ID, Task Name and Task Status. Each worker has four tasks, Task-1 through Task-4. Each task can have one of two status: Completed or Open. The four tasks are dependent, i.e., later task(s) cannot be Completed until preceding task(s) are completed. I am writing a SSRS report to pull these information out. In the report, I want to display Worker ID/Task Names/Task Status when at least one task is Open (i.e., hide the ones that all four tasks have been completed). Also I want to tally the number of workers that have at least one open task (I figured this out by CountDistinct(WorkerID)), as well as the number of workers that have only Task-4 open (could not figure this out). I have attached a sketch of the report that I wanted in the picture. [image]
Please note: I DO NOT want worker 3 to show since all four tasks have been completed for that worker. If I filtered on the data set by only allowing Open tasks, then the 'Completed' rows for the other two workers are filtered out which is not what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you could do this in the dataset and then simply show the output in your report.

The Idea is to group your dataset by your workerid and tast status looking for count <4 or task status = 'OPEN' - In case all four tasks are open.

have a look at this sql fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e051c/1/0

This should give you the output you desire.

Incase the Fiddle fails -

```
create table workers 
 (
workerid int
,taskname varchar (10)
,taskstatus varchar(10)
) ;

insert into workers (workerid,taskname,taskstatus )
values 
(1,'Task-1','Completed'),
(1  , 'Task-2'  ,'Open'  ),
(1  , 'Task-3'  ,'Open'  ),
(1  , 'Task-4'  ,'Open'  ),
(2  , 'Task-1'  ,'Completed'  ),
(2  , 'Task-2'  ,'Completed'  ),
(2  , 'Task-3'  ,'Completed'  ),
(2  , 'Task-4'  ,'Open'  ),
(3  , 'Task-1'  ,'Completed'  ),
(3  , 'Task-2'  ,'Completed'  ),
(3  , 'Task-3'  ,'Completed'  ),
(3  , 'Task-4'  ,'Completed'  ),
(4  , 'Task-1'  ,'Open'  ),
(4  , 'Task-2'  ,'Open'  ),
(4  , 'Task-3'  ,'Open'  ),
(4  , 'Task-4'  ,'Open' ) 
 
 
;with valid_workers as (
   Select distinct
    workerID 
 
from workers 
group by
workerID 
,taskstatus
having count(*) <4 or taskstatus = 'Open'  
)
 

Select w.*

from workers w
    inner join valid_workers v
        on v.workerID = w.workerID ;
```

-- Result

```
| workerid | taskname | taskstatus |
|----------|----------|------------|
|        1 |   Task-1 |  Completed |
|        1 |   Task-2 |       Open |
|        1 |   Task-3 |       Open |
|        1 |   Task-4 |       Open |
|        2 |   Task-1 |  Completed |
|        2 |   Task-2 |  Completed |
|        2 |   Task-3 |  Completed |
|        2 |   Task-4 |       Open |
|        4 |   Task-1 |       Open |
|        4 |   Task-2 |       Open |
|        4 |   Task-3 |       Open |
|        4 |   Task-4 |       Open |
```

Comment: Thanks, Harry. The problem I have is I am bound by existing stored procedures. I can't create my own Dataset in Report Builder. So whatever grouping I do I can only do it in a paginated report. Any way to implement this in Report Builder? I was playing with group variables. But since I can't loop the variable over itself, I can't create a counter that way...

Comment: OK, in that case, how about you create a derived column in your dataset. Call it taststatusint or something and assign it a value of 1 if open and 0 if completed. So you should be able to sum on this column at a group level. A sum of 0 would indiciate all completed. So set a visibility or a filter on the group to say if sum of taststatusint = 0 then hide else show

Comment: Thank you Harry. I ended up creating a group (WorkerID) variable to count the number of completed tasks within the group. Then I set the row visibility conditionally on the value of that group variable. That worked!